# how do i properly assign a price, then calculate price by quantity? javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-experience

> (the javascript is in a separate file for tidy purposes)
>
> this is my first time posting a question
>
> im learning to create a website, i have multiple inputs in the html.
> I also want to output   the total for both individually and as well as
> all together in an estimate within the   bottom of the website.
>
> individually ItemPrice * Quantity;
>
> all together = total price;
>
> hope this makes sense??## Heading ##

---

```
 // Calculating Function for Tier3
function price(Tier3) {
    var Tier1 = document.getElementById("Tier3");//Getting ID
    Tier3 = 1.4;

    var Tier1 = document.getElementById("Tier2");//Getting ID
    Tier2 = 1.6;

    var Tier1 = document.getElementById("Tier1");//Getting ID
    Tier1 = 1.8;

    var RAM = document.getElementById("RAM");//Getting ID
    RAM = 3.45; //assigning value

    var vCPU = document.getElementsByID("vCPU"); //Getting ID
    vCPU = 2.54; // assigning price?

    var price = parseFloat($('#price').text()) || 0;
    var qty = parseInt($('#quantity').val());
    var total = price * qty;
    $('#total').text(total);

}
```

Comment: can you also include your html as well?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out, thanks guys!
// Calculating Function for Tier3
function price() {

```
var Tier3 = document.getElementById("Tier3");//Getting ID
//Tier3 = 1.4;

var Tier2 = document.getElementById("Tier2");//Getting ID
//Tier2 = 1.6;

var Tier1 = document.getElementById("Tier1");//Getting ID
//Tier1 = 1.8;

var RAM = document.getElementById("RAM");//Getting ID
//RAM = 3.45; //assigning value

var vCPU = document.getElementById("vCPU"); //Getting ID

var totalPerItem = document.getElementById("totalPerItem")

totalPerItem.innerHTML = "$" + ((vCPU.value * 2.54) + (RAM.value * 3.45) + (Tier1.value * 1.8) + (Tier2.value * 1.6) + (Tier3.value * 1.4)); // assigning price?
```

}

Comment: Edit your question with correct `indentation`.